# Why this QC probability drop to $|01⟩$ and $|11⟩$ instead of $|10⟩$ and $|11⟩$?

Tags: quantum-state, probability, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I have QC like this

[image]

The final state before measure should be $|1⟩ ⊗ |-⟩$, and it will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10⟩ - |11⟩)$, so the probability of this QC should be a half is $|10⟩$ and other half is $|11⟩$. But the result of this QC is a half is $|01⟩$ and other half is $|11⟩$.

[image]

Can someone explain me why?
The script is down below.

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

simulator = AerSimulator()
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.x(0)
circuit.x(1)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.measure_all()
circuit.draw('mpl')

compiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
job = simulator.run(compiled_circuit, shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
plot_histogram(counts)

print(counts)
```

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that states are labeled from right to left? Try the H gate on q0 and see if the labeling reverses.

Comment: Oh, you are right, the result become |10⟩ and |11⟩, should read the label from right to left.